# DAX Date Month Names Column through switch

Tags: date, switch-statement

I want to get Month names for a DIM_time table. I try to get this through the Swith Statement as follows: 
MonthName = 
SWITCH('Dim Time test'[Month], 
        1, "January", 
        2, "February", 
        3, "March", 
        4, "April", 
        5, "May", 
        6, "June", 
        7, "July", 
        8, "August", 
        9, "September", 
        10, "October", 
        11, "November", 
        12, "December", 
        "Unknown month number")

I receive the following error: The syntax for '"January"' is incorrect. (DAX(SWITCH('Dim Time test'[Month], 1. "January", 2. "February", 3. "March", 4. "April", 5. "May", 6. "June", 7. "July", 8. "August", 9. "September", 10. "October", 11. "November", 12. "December", "Unknown month number") )).

Any ideas how I can obtain the desired result? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seperate all with a semicolon. Works with Power BI.

MonthName = SWITCH([Month]; 1; "January"; 2; "February"; 3; "March"; 4; "April"; 5; "May"; 6; "June"; 7; "July"; 8; "August"; 9; "September"; 10; "October"; 11; "November"; 12; "December"; "Unknown month number")

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for Power BI Desktop is -

```
MonthName = SWITCH([month number], 1, "January", 2, "February", 3, "March", 4, "April", 5, "May", 6, "June", 7, "July", 8, "August", 9, "September", 10, "October", 11, "November", 12, "December", "Unknown month number")
```